# Adhesive suggestions for pebbles and shells on cardboard

Tags: adhesives

I'm looking to suggestions on what glue would be best to stick smooth stones and shells to a reasonably sturdy piece pf cardboard to be put upright in a shadow box/deep frame. Would epoxy be the best way to go? I'll need something pretty strong as I certainly don't want any to fall ofd! I'd really appreciate any information anyone may have. Thank you

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate: there's a world of difference between gluing pebbles and shells to each other and gluing pebbles and shells to a piece of cardboard.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that some standard silicone would be strong and cheap. They are all guaranteed to stick to cement, bricks... And pebbles and shells are made of similar materials.

Of course, you need to clean the pebbles and shells properly, before applying any glue.

Comment: But is silicone going to stay put on cardboard? Or is it just going to peel off?

Comment: I have some plans to glue cardboard with silicone, but I did not do it yet, so I cannot guarantee. However, I saw ornaments with things glued on cardboard, using the hot-glue / hot-gun "silicone". That's why I assume that normal silicone might have a good chance to work. The only problem is the quality of the cardboard itself - which might peel regardless of the glue being used.

Comment: Silicone glue isn't the same thing as hot glue, though, is it?